# When 1 condition is true , 2 actions should take place at the same time in netlogo

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

When a turtle moves to a particular patch, the patch should change colour and that turtle should die.
I know this can be done in if condition statements but how?

I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
 to go   
    ask turtles [ 
      ask patches with [ pcolor = black ] 
      [ 
        if any? turtles-here with [ color = yellow  ] 
        [
          (set pcolor yellow) or ( one-of turtles-here die)] 
        ]
    ]
end
```

Also there are many turtles, but only one turtle should die when this condition is given, and when the next turtle comes near this patch, it should move away.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
ask one-of patches with [pcolor = black 
                         and 
                         any? turtles-here with [color = yellow]] [
  set pcolor yellow 
  ask one-of turtles-here [die]
]
```